# Why does this function return 3125

Tags: python, expression, pow

Today I saw a function in a python textbook, the code is below:

```
def power(x,y):
    return pow(x,y)
```

When I gave params to the `power` like below:

```
>>>params=(5,)*2
>>>power(*params)  
3125
```

The function returned me a 3125. I know 3125 may be came from (5*5)*(5*5)*5,but I don't understand how working is the params in the code. What the meaning of the expression `(5,)*2`?

Comment: Did you check what `params` is? That should answer this.

Answer (score 2):

That's a concatenation of a tuple.

```
>>>(5,)*2
(5,5)
>>>(5,)*5
(5,5,5,5,5)
```

Comment: I got the method to add a value to a tuple.2*(5,)==(5,5)

Comment: `2*(5,)==(5,)*2`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `(5,)*2` expands to `(5, 5)`, aka is a *tuple*.  See the docs on [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) .

Re `pow()`: according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow), `pow(x,y)` returns *x to the power y*:

In your script, you use the * in `power(*params)` to insert the two items in the `params` tuple as individual parameters into the function. You could have achieved the same by typing `power(5,5)`.

Thus, 5^5, which equals 3125.

A intuitive tutorial on tuples is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).

Comment: I got the method to add a value to a tuple.2*(5,)==(5,5),  pow(5,5)=3125

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the value of `params`, you can see how it works:

```
>>> params=(5,)*2
>>> params
(5, 5)
>>> power(*params)
3125
```

`*n` applied to a sequence returns that sequence appended to itself `n` times ([see documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common)).

Comment: I got the method to add a value to a tuple.2*(5,)==(5,5),  pow(5,5)=3125